# can not pass date to function correctly

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION testing_lockstep(_id_arr int[], _counter_arr int[], d_date date)
  RETURNS TABLE (uc__id int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS  
$func$
DECLARE
   _id int;
   _counter int;
  d_date date; 
BEGIN
   FOR _id, _counter IN 
      SELECT *
      FROM   unnest (_id_arr, _counter_arr) t  -- !!
   LOOP
   
   
   
   RETURN QUERY


with orig_dataset as (

select a.uc_id, cr.imei,cr.points_geom ,cr.created_at as time_created
from campaign_routes cr 
left join assets a on a.imei = cr.imei

where cr.created_at::date > d_date
)


select uc_id
from orig_dataset;



END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

My function call is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM testing_lockstep('{454,454}'::int[]
                             , '{2,3}'::int[], TO_DATE('2017-01-03','YYYY-MM-DD') );
```

The issue is I am getting a null result set, even though if I hardcode the same date in the function body, then I am getting correct results, i.e. if I write:

```
where cr.created_at::date > '2023-01-17'::date
```

then I am getting correct results.

Please note, in the main function body, I have ommited parts for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is allowed to declare a variable with the same name as a parameter, that is than used *instead* of the parameter.

Simple remove the duplicated declaration of `d_date` from your function and it will start to *work*;)

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION testing_lockstep(_id_arr int[], _counter_arr int[], d_date date)
  RETURNS TABLE (uc__id int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS  
$func$
DECLARE
   _id int;
   _counter int;
-- comment this out -->>>>  d_date date;
```